# How to dynamically configure a REST mock in SoapUi?

Tags: rest, mocking, soapui

Using SoapUi I intend to make a call to a MockService and when the Response is configured to return a static message, everything seems to be fine. On the other side, if I add and send a parameter (Eg. ?PName=John), although I also changed the name in the response from "John" to ${PName}, i get nothing (an empty string). Where am I doing it wrong? Please see the attached screenshot

Thank you,[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would get the request parameters:

For example, user is passing a query parameter say `test` with value `abc`.

Mock Script:

```groovy
//Read request parameter test and assign value to a variable
def userValue = mockRequest.httpRequest.getParameter('test')
//Assign the input value to response context
context.requestValue = userValue
```

Sample response using the context:

```json
{
  "comment" : "${requestValue}"
}
```

Over all flow of data:

[image]

Comment: @user1980253, glad to know. Would you mind accepting it as answer then?

Answer (score -1):

Use concept of properties for parametrisation.
Mock Services uses the properties Value. 
As your property PName is not present in Custom Properties at any level of soapUI, so you are getting NULL response.

Define a property PnameValue Project Level as

[image]

Now modify your Test Request value as [image]

Add a Mock Service with response

[image]

Start your mock Service and Trigger operation.Also you can you use different Response based on Property Values at any level of SoapUI.

Please Accept answer if it solve your problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Because, just using the project property and it is impossible to have same value for all the request calls and not at all solve the purpose of sending value as query parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not answer my question. I need to pass the parameter as a "classical" REST param.